# Jquery $.post sending portugese text to php and saving it to database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

Here's my data from firebug

```
action=saveOrder&name=Aprova%C3%A7%C3%A3o+dos
```

On the server side I am trying to save it to database, the name column has collation - utf8_general_ci

Here's my php script
1.

```
 $name= htmlentities(str_replace("+", " ", rawurldecode($_POST["name"])));
```

I also tried 
2.

```
 $name= html_entity_decode(str_replace("+", " ", rawurldecode($_POST["name"])));
```

If you see this link 
http://writecodeonline.com/php/
The 2. piece work there, but when I save it in database it's not saved properly
with the last code piece the value that gets saved is AprovaÃ§Ã£o dos and with case 1.
it saves this AprovaÃ§Ã£o dos

The value that should get saved in database is Aprovação dos

```
function saveorders()
{
  var params={};
  params.action='saveOrder';
  params.name=$("#cliente_nome").val();
  $.post('saveorders.php',params,function(data)
  {
    alert(data);
  });
}
```

PHP Code

```
 <?php

  mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
  include_once ("clase.php");// Database connection file
  session_start();
  $name=html_entity_decode(str_replace("+", " ", rawurldecode($_POST["name"])));
  Policy::saveOrders($name);

  ?>
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps I took to resolve this

1. Set the collation  of database table to utf8_general_ci
2. The PHP Page which is receiving the data, set its header to mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); and iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");
   [This one I took from the above answers, I am not sure which one to keep and which one to remove, I kept both as it worked for me]
   3.while sending data using jquery use escape, so this becomes

   ```
    params.name=$("#cliente_nome").val();
   ```

   this

   ```
     params.name=escape($("#cliente_nome").val());
   ```
3. The server page should use rawurlencode method
   e.g

```
 <?php

  mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
  iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");
  include_once ("clase.php");// Database connection file
  session_start();
  $name=str_replace("+", " ", rawurldecode($_POST["name"]));
  Policy::saveOrders($name);

  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create your link between your website and database, set it to UTF-8. Also, save yours PHP pages using ANSI as UTF-8 (UTF-8 encoding without BOM). Be sure yours database and tables use UTF-8 encoding also. Set the internal encoding of php to UTF-8.

Comment: @Sandhurst Yes, of corse. I will edit in 2 sec. What type of library you use between PHP and MySQL ? mysql, mysqli or PDO ?

Comment: I think its mysql mysql_connect

Comment: `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");//Set PHP internal encoding`

Comment: still the same result $name= html_entity_decode(str_replace("+", " ", rawurldecode($_POST["name"]))); the value which got saved is AprovaÃ§Ã£o dos

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the file encoding (the .php file itself) is UTF-8.

Also, add header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8'); to your UTF-8 pages and see if it helps.

Comment: I have added mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); to my php page which is receiving the data but still I am not able to save it in the format in which user is entering

Comment: try www.php.net/iconv (something like iconv('ISO-8859-1','UTF-8',$string)). Other than that, I need to see your code (the link that you posted don't show it), try editing your _question_ and adding the relevant portion of the code to it.

Comment: I have edited my question, now it contains the code piece as well